# Find items and chech if it has the same id as in parent scope and if it has add isDisable to item

Tags: javascript, algorithm, object, search, nested

Hi everyone I need to get advice on how to realize such a function for searching and adding property if the children's scope has the same ids as the parent scope and add `isDisable` key.

The data which I got and I need to transform it with new property `isDisable`

```
const data = [
  {
   id: "MT1",
   children: []
  },
  {
   id: "MT2",
   children: []
  },
  {
   id: "MT4",
   children: []
  },
  {
   id: "1234",
   children: [
    {
     id: "MT1",
     children: []
    },
    {
     id: "MT65",
     children: []
    },
   ]
  },
  {
   id: "537465",
   children: [{
     id: "MT1",
     children: []
    },
    {
     id: "MT2",
     children: [
      {
       id: "MT1",
       children: []
      },
      {
       id: "MT12",
       children: []
      }
     ]
    },
   ]
  }
]
```

This is some function for searching and adding a property to an item and result.

```
const someSearchFunction = (data) => {}

console.log(someSearchFunction(data))

const data = [
  {
   id: "MT1",
   children: [],
   isDisable: false
  },
  {
   id: "MT2",
   children: [],
   isDisable: false
  },
  {
   id: "MT4",
   children: [],
   isDisable: false
  },
  {
   id: "MT12",
   children: [],
   isDisable: false
  },
  {
   id: "1234",
   children: [
    {
     id: "MT1",
     children: [],
     isDisable: true
    },
    {
     id: "MT65",
     children: [],
     isDisable: false
    },
   ]
  },
  {
   id: "537465",
   children: [
    {
     id: "MT1",
     children: [],
     isDisable: true
    },
    {
     id: "42354322",
     children: [
      {
       id: "MT1",
       children: [],
       isDisable: true
      },
      {
       id: "MT12",
       children: []
       isDisable: false
      }
     ]
    },
   ]
  }
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your requested result doesn't make much sense to me.  Are you disabling all those items at any level if there is an item *at the root* that has the same id?  We could certainly do that, as the answer from *minikdev* shows.  But usually I've seen something slightly different: disabling something if *any of its ancestors* has the same id.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Hi, yes we have a table with children and we loop through the elements from top to bottom if at the first level we have a list of ids
["MT1", "MT2", "MT4", "MT12"] next nested level has id such `1234`  and this level has ids ["MT1", "MT65"] we have to add `isDisable` for a child with ID - ['MT1'] because one level up we have the same ID, then we have next item with id `537465` which has children one has id `MT1` we have to add `isDisable` because one level up we have the same ID but we have next level with ID `42354322` which has "MT1" we have to add `isDisable` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by capturing the list of ids for the current level to pass on to the recursive call for our children.

Here is a version which does not mutate the input -- we're not barbarians! -- but returns a new tree with the `isDisable` property set appropiately.

```js
const disableDupIds = (xs, ids = [], currLevel = xs .map (x => x .id)) => {
  return xs .map (({id, children, ...rest}) => ({
    id, 
    ...rest,
    isDisable: ids .includes (id),
    children: disableDupIds (children, currLevel)
  }))
}

const data = [{id: "MT1", children: []}, {id: "MT2", children: []}, {id: "MT4", children: []}, {id: "1234", children: [{id: "MT1", children: []}, {id: "MT65", children: []}]}, {id: "537465", children: [{id: "MT1", children: []}, {id: "MT2", children: [{id: "MT1", children: []}, {id: "MT12", children: []}]}]}]

console .log (disableDupIds (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We first capture the list of ids in our current level, then simply map over our elements, returning new versions with `isDisable` set `true` when our current id is in the list from the previous level, and recurring on our children, using our blacklist of current level ids.

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output is not a valid array, better check it.

You can try this function:

```
const someSearchFunction = (data) => {
data.forEach(item => {
    item.isDisable = false
    item.children.some(child => {
        if (data.some(parent => {
            return parent.id === child.id
        })) {
            child.isDisable = true
        } else {
            child.isDisable = false
        }
    }
    )
})
```

}